# Changing tablespace increment size

Tags: oracle, tablespace

One of our datafiles hit the max of 32G.  So, we created a 2nd datafile in that tablespace.

However, we forgot to give a default NEXT size.  So, file 1 has a NEXT of 50MB.  And file 2 has a NEXT of 8k.

These are locally managed, so, I am guessing the only thing to do is create a new tablespace, and move all the objects.  Or is there another solution?  One question:  How do I move TYPES?   Do I need to drop & recreate those?  Which will invalidate a ton of things.......

Any suggestions?  Can I isolate the objects in just that datafile?

Thanking you.

Comment: instead of adding 2 data file you can create " BIG FILE"  which can grow very big size.

and BIGFILE supports  chan NEXT value                                      ALTER TABLESPACE my_TBS_name AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 20G;

Answer (score 5):

You should always consult [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm) first. What you ask for is a straightforward, [single-SQL-command-involving action](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_1004.htm#SQLRF00802). The crucial piece of knowledge you missed is that you do not alter a tablespace, you [alter a datafile](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_1004.htm#i2188492).

**Proof of concept**

First, I'll just query my `example` tablespace for its block size, as I'll use the value for proving that my datafile was altered correctly.

```
SQL> select tablespace_name, block_size
SQL> from dba_tablespaces
SQL> where tablespace_name = 'EXAMPLE';

TABLESPACE_NAME                BLOCK_SIZE
------------------------------ ----------
EXAMPLE                              8192
```

OK, the tbs uses a block size of 8KB.

Now, what my `example` data files look like?

```
SQL> select file_name, file_id, tablespace_name, autoextensible, increment_by * &example_tbs_block_size_b / 1048576 as increment_by_mbytes
SQL> from dba_data_files
SQL> where tablespace_name = 'EXAMPLE';

FILE_NAME                          FILE_ID    TABLESPACE_NAME AUTOEXTENSIBLE INCREMENT_BY_MBYTES
---------------------------------- ---------- --------------- -------------- -------------------
D:\ORA\MY_CDB\MY_PDB\EXAMPLE01.DBF         10 EXAMPLE         YES                              1
```

OK, I see just a single data file with the autoextend of 1MB.

Now alter the datafile...

```
SQL> alter database datafile 10 autoextend on next &target_autoextend maxsize unlimited;

Database altered
```

And recheck the tbs datafiles once again

```
SQL> select file_name, file_id, tablespace_name, autoextensible, increment_by * &example_tbs_block_size_b / 1048576 as increment_by_mbytes
SQL> from dba_data_files
SQL> where tablespace_name = 'EXAMPLE';

FILE_NAME                          FILE_ID    TABLESPACE_NAME AUTOEXTENSIBLE INCREMENT_BY_MBYTES
---------------------------------- ---------- --------------- -------------- -------------------
D:\ORA\MY_CDB\MY_PDB\EXAMPLE01.DBF         10 EXAMPLE         YES                              8
```

And, voilá, I have an autoextend of 8MB.

Comment: Will this work in case of temp files as well?

Comment: @kamalpreet, yes, it will, just remember that in that case you don't alter a "datafile", but you alter a "tempfile". The rest remains the same.